# Trouble centering search bar within div

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a search bar in the header of my site. It is an input within a div. I just can't seem to figure out how to center the searchbar in the middle of the div. I have it set up perfectly in terms of responsiveness so I don't want to change the way it's positioned besides just centering it. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

HTML:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
  <div>
    <label hidden="true" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input placeholder="I want to go see lighthouses" class="text" type="text" value="I want to go see lighthouses" name="I want to go see lighthouses" id="s" onfocus="(this.value == 'I want to go see lighthouses') && (this.value = '')" onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'I want to go see lighthouses')" />
    <input hidden="true" type="submit" class="submit" name="Submit" value="Search!" />
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#searchform div {
  shadow: 4px 7px 4px #000000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 90px;
}

#searchform .text {
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  background: white url('images/search-img.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 96% center;
  font-size: 220%;
  color: #B7B7B7;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#searchform .text:focus {
  background-image: none;
}

#searchform .text img {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-align` to the wrapping div to center the inline contents.

```css
   #searchform div {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     bottom: 90px;
     text-align: center/* Text align here */     
   }


   #searchform .text {
     font-family: 'Merriweather';
     background: white url('images/search-img.png') no-repeat;
     background-position: 96% center;
     font-size: 220%;
     color: #B7B7B7;
     border-radius: 50px;
     padding-left: 35px;
     height: 75px;
     width: 100%; /* Updated thiese two widths, better for your responsive design */
     max-width: 600px;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
   #searchform .text:focus {
     background-image: none;
   }
   #searchform .text img {
     margin-right: 25px;
   }
```

```html
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
  <div>
    <label hidden="true" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input placeholder="I want to go see lighthouses" class="text" type="text" value="I want to go see lighthouses" name="I want to go see lighthouses" id="s" onfocus="(this.value == 'I want to go see lighthouses') && (this.value = '')" onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'I want to go see lighthouses')"
    />
    <input hidden="true" type="submit" class="submit" name="Submit" value="Search!" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS for `#searchform div` to:

```
#searchform div {
  shadow: 4px 7px 4px #000000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 90px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/abeLnj2L/).

Answer (score 0):

Just align the text in the div (which would include inline and inline-block elements) to the center.

```
#searchform div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 90px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/hzd2ao0L/)

Answer (score 0):

try `text-align: center` for "#searchform div`

Answer (score 0):

change `display: inline-block` to `block`.

```
#searchform .text {
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  background: white url('images/search-img.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 96% center;
  font-size: 220%;
  color: #B7B7B7;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block; //change this to block
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

check this - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGPQjZ?editors=110